# Is the normality of two normal numbers preserved under pairwise concatenation of their digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

We work in ***base-10***. If $a$ and $b$ are two real [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) irrational numbers with decimal expansion written as $a_1a_2\ldots a_n\ldots$ and $b_1b_2\ldots b_n\ldots$  respectively, I write $a\oplus b$ for the number formed by concatenating the n-th digit of $a$ to the ***left***  of the n-th digit of $b$. Explicitly $$a\oplus b=a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots a_nb_n\ldots$$

> ***Question***: is $a\oplus b$ normal ?

Intuitively to me the answer is yes. At a minimum I would expect $a\oplus b$ to be simply normal. But then I am not ever certain $a\oplus b$ is irrational. Here is what I know:

$$(a\oplus b)\oplus c=a\oplus (b\oplus c)$$
$$a\oplus b \neq b\oplus a$$
$$a\oplus b=a\oplus c \implies \text{ }b=c$$
$$b\oplus a=c\oplus a \implies \text{ }b=c$$

***Edit***: Following the suggestion of a comment I have replaced "$+$" with "$\oplus$"

Comment: I would recommend using a different symbol than $+$ for representing this concatenation operation., perhaps `\oplus` $\oplus$ or `\star` $\star$ or `\circ` $\circ$., people at a glance might not read your first paragraph and misinterpret the question as being about the addition of two normal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. have $b = a$, and then your new number is not normal: the distribution of pairs is wrong.

Comment: could you walk me through the reasoning?

Comment: At least half the pairs are of the form $xx$.

Comment: Would this be the only "exception" ?

Comment: No, there will be infinitely many.  Try $b = c-a$ where $c$ is rational.